# Highchart draw rows at bottom of the chart align with axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

See the attached image. So basically What I need is to draw rows with the chart. Like in image below, I want to show temperature on the chart as a line and snow/rain on the rows aligned with the axis. I have the temperature, rain and snow data in my series array.

Sample Data (For rain and snow, 1 mean yes):

```
series: [{
        type: 'line',
        data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,3,9,7],
        name: 'Temperature'
    }, {
        data: [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
        name: 'Rain'
    },{
        data: [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
        name: 'Snow'
    }]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you paste your sample data here?

Comment: @morganfree I updated the questions with some sample data. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/Renderer) to draw a table but the data will not be treated as series but they will be simple static numbers with lines. However, you can use a heatmap series to have a chart as in the image.

You need 4 y axis - 1 for line, 2 for labels and the last two for snow and rain. The rest is adjusting axis positions though height and top properties.

```
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
  spacingBottom: 0,
  marginBottom: 0
},
legend: {
  enabled: false
},
credits: {
  enabled: false
},
xAxis: {
  visible: false
},
yAxis: [{
  height: '60%',
  title: {
    text: null
  }
}, {
  height: '10%',
  top: '60%',
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  offset: 0,
  endOnTick: false,
  startOnTick: false,
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  visible: false
}, {
  height: '10%',
  top: '70%',
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  offset: 0,
  //    min: 0, max: 0,
  endOnTick: false,
  startOnTick: false,
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  categories: ['Rain']
}, {
  height: '10%',
  top: '80%',
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  offset: 0,
  endOnTick: false,
  startOnTick: false,
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  categories: ['Snow']
}],

colorAxis: {
  stops: [
    [0, 'white'],
    [1, 'red']
  ]
},

plotOptions: {
  heatmap: {
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 0.5
  }
},

series: [{
  data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 9, 7],
  name: 'Temperature',
  step: 'left'
}, {
  yAxis: 1,
  type: 'heatmap',
  data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11].map(v => [0, v, 'white']),
  showInLegend: false,
  enableMouseTracking: false,
  keys: ['y', 'value', 'color'],
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true
  }
}, {
  yAxis: 2,
  type: 'heatmap',
  data: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].map(v => [0, v]),
  name: 'Rain'
}, {
  type: 'heatmap',
  yAxis: 3,
  data: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0].map(v => [0, v]),
  name: 'Snow'
}]

});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/euLz99mk/

Comment: Looks very good. One quick questions, When I add another y-axis, something happens to the format. For example, if you add {
                title: {
                    text: "Something else"
                }
            } to the jsfiddle, you will see the issue. any idea?

Comment: I only added this to what you got,     {
                opposite: true,
                title: {
                    text: "dew point"
             }
          }

Comment: You changed top and height of the first and you changed connection between series and axis. Heatmap series are connected to the specific axes - so if you change the order of the y axis and position it incorrectly you will get what you instructed. You can connect series with axis by id - http://jsfiddle.net/s5m20dfo/1/

Comment: I figured it after posting the previous comment. thanks